# Python - how to convert 1/0 to yes/no (in pandas.DataFrame)?

Tags: python, r, pandas

In **R**, if I want to create a new column with YES/NO based on another column with `1` and `0`, the following code serves my purpose.

```
df <- data.frame(alpha = c(50, 51, 52), beta = c(1,0,1))
df$gamma <- factor(df$beta, label = c('no','yes'))

  alpha beta gamma
1    50    1   yes
2    51    0    no
3    52    1   yes
```

But I am not sure how to do the same in **Python**. Can anyone finish the following code or suggest different methods?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'alpha': [50, 51, 52], 'beta': [1,0,1]})
df['gamma'] = ??????
```

Thanks in advance. (The simpler, the better)

Comment: Arguably it isn't the *simplest* solution, but if you're mapping a set of integers to strings, you could consider using categorical dtypes: `df['gamma'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(df.beta, categories=["no", "yes"])` (which is closer to the R solution as I understand it) - it should be fast and memory efficient too.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is for conversions in the *other* direction (str -> int, as opposed to int -> str).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), which accepts a dictionary input:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'alpha': [50, 51, 52], 'beta': [1,0,1]})

df['gamma'] = df['beta'].map({True: 'yes', False: 'no'})
```

Comment: map does not work on dataframes, I think.